# Python Azure Function performance

Tags: python, postgresql, azure-functions

I have a pretty basic python script that is deployed as an Azure Function (Consumption Plan), it just makes some database queries and some API calls to format a list and iterate through that list (length is ~500k) and make calls to the last API. Lastly, data is extracted from the json formated as a data frame and inserted into a Postgres instance. For postgres inserts I'm turning the resulting dataframe to a list of tuples and inserting using execute().

I've run it locally and it takes about 12 minutes to process 3k calls. and it will currently time out at 30 minutes.

Given the basic information above, are there any methods for improving the speed of the azure function?
I was looking at multiprocessing, but that seems a bit redundant given the elastic nature of azure functions. I've also considered caching the list, but those steps are pretty fast to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your script is doing, Azure Functions may not find enough reason to scale your app out and add more worker instances. Your app seems to be I/O bound, and in this case increasing [FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#functions_worker_process_count) will probably help. See [Scaling and concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#scaling-and-concurrency) for more details.